# How to resize a exfat raw unpartitioned filesystem image

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora, windows-10-v1703, exfat

Just a simple question… But I couldn’t found how to do it…
I’ve a 250Gb unpartitionned fileystem image which I need to copy on a low end 250Gb ꜱᴅ card with a write speed below 500Kb/s.

The image has 40% free space. So this means I would be able to save a lot of hours by only copying allocated data. But I also can’t perform a file by file copy (or the exfat driver end up crashing with handling so much files which force me to reformat the target ꜱᴅ card from scratch and chkdsk fails to fix such errors on Windows).

So the only option is to shrink the backup image I created with `dd` ; then copy it on the low end target ꜱᴅ card and grow filesystem in order to fill partition.

The problem is (of course) partition guru doesn’t accept to resize filesystems which are partition less, nor (the option is grayed out) it allow me to change partition size on the ꜱᴅ card.

Comment: Whether I’m using using Windows® or Fedora, file by file copy doesn’t works (everything happens has if I would have bad blocks but `chkdsk /R` finds nothing). Whereas I’ve no problem so far with `dd` copying though I can’t finish it in a reasonable amount of time..

Comment: Which exFAT driver is crashing, the Linux or Windows one?

Comment: @grawity : as I said in the previous comment : both. I end up with directories I can’t delete nor modify and `chkdsk` can’t fix those fileystem errors. So reformatting from scratch is the only option to fix such filesystem errors. Maybe it would works with the filesystem driver of ᴏꜱX but I don’t own a Macintosh for checking.